# Administrator permissions for login system php

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, permissions, admin

```
<?php session_start();

$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
$_SESSION['password'] = $_POST['password'];


$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'smithrwg_user', 'password', 'smithrwg_database');

$_SESSION['username'] = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_SESSION['username']);
$query = "SELECT password, salt
        FROM tbl_mem
        WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "';";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);


if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0) // User not found. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    echo "not found";
    session_destroy();
}



$userData = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
$hash = hash('sha256', $userData['salt'] . hash('sha256', $_SESSION['password']) );
if($hash != $userData['password']) // Incorrect password. So, redirect to login_form again.
{
    header('Location: login.html');
}else {
// Redirect to home page after successful login.


    header('Location: index.php');
    $_SESSION['priv'] = $row['priv'];

}
?>
```

i am trying to set $_SESSION['priv'] = to the row in the mysql database table "tbl_mem" priv. but at the moment its not setting it to anything and i don't really understand how to make it do that.

Comment: how about $row[0]['priv'];
assign the first result/priv to the session

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$row` is not defined, you probably meant to write `$userData`. But still this won't work - you will need to edit your query as well.

```
$query = "SELECT password, salt, priv FROM...";
//...
$_SESSION['priv'] = $userData['priv'];
header('Location: index.php');
```

It should be put in front of `header()` to make sure the value is really assigned

Comment: You are welcome! I suggest using `error_reporting(E_ALL);` in your development environment, so you can easily track what is going wrong.